# Separating values in one column into separate columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have two columns of data in my table and in the second is a mix of different information, is it possible to separate the data in the second column into separate columns based on information type so that I only have one row per Hotel ID? Eg.

**From this:**
**Hotel ID   Details**
1                 Paris
1                  France
1                  EMEA
2                  Munich
2                 Germany
2                 EMEA
3                 Christchurch
3                 New Zealand
3                 APAC

**To this:**
**Hotel ID                City                        Country                Country Region**
1                          Paris                     France                       EMEA
2                         Munich                  Germany                  EMEA
3                         Christchurch          New Zealand           APAC

Comment: Is there another field which gtd's the sequence?

Comment: What does GTD stand for?

Comment: Sorry... guarantee.  With a proper sequence order, it would be a small matter to pivot your data

Answer (score 2):

From the data you posted there's no way to tell if i.e. `EMEA` is a `City`, `Country` or `Country region`. You need to have more data in your table like i.e. `type` column or so indicating what is what.